How to explicitly destroy all singletons created by boost::di?
I have several different objects created by an injector created by boost::di. These objects are created in so-called di::singleton scope. When I tested, these objects seem to be destroyed at the application exit.
Instead, I would like them to be destroyed earlier, as I leave a scope where those objects are in any way relevant. This should happen to all objects created by the injector automatically; I don't want to explicitly list all those objects.
How do I achieve that?
